# Einsum creates overflow. Why?

Tags: python, numpy

Here is the code that works :

```py
for iElem in range(nElem) :
      nodes      = elem[iElem]
      x          = X[nodes]
      y          = Y[nodes]
      jac        = abs((x[0]-x[1]) * (y[0]-y[2]) - (x[0]-x[2])* (y[0]-y[1]))
      B[iElem,:] = np.dot(Ainverse,B[iElem])/jac
```

Here is the code that doesn't work

```py
    x2          = X[elem]
    y2          = Y[elem]
    jac2        = abs((x2[:,0] - x2[:,1]) * (y2[:,0]-y2[:,2]) - (x2[:,0]-x2[:,2])* (y2[:,0]-y2[:,1]))
    iJac2       = np.power(jac2,-1)
    K           = np.zeros(np.shape(B))
    F           = np.zeros(np.shape(B))
    K           = np.einsum('ih,jh->ji',Ainverse,B)
    F           = np.einsum('ih,i->ih',K,iJac2)
    B           = F
```

Apparently when I print B with the naïve method and B with the einsum method it contains the same elements but when I use it the next of my code doesn't have the same value and shows warning:

RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in multiply

RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in add
.
.
.

. The errors seems unrelated to the change of code but that's the only thing that changes from one run without errors and one with errors

In my view this bug is not understandable at all.

I've tried looking for dtype difference in the array created by numpy but they are the same in both approach.

Comment: I Just saw that the problem occurs only when I call the function multiple times

Comment: I found the solution by modifying the line B=F by B[:,:] = F[:,:]. I guess that it works because B=F change the pointer B to the memory place of F and B[:,:] = F[:,:] change the value in B by those in F